# In neo4j, how can I index by date and search in a date range?

Tags: java, search, indexing, neo4j

In neo4j, how can I index by date and search in a date range. Also for times, I would like to search between 8am and 9am in a date range as well.

Comment: Btw, why not use Cipher?

Comment: How is cipher going to help me index?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Index the dates and times as integer timestamps. Then you can easily search in an index for dates between other timestamps. You can also index the time part of the timestamp separately as another integer, allowing you to query for specific times between given dates.

Example:
The date and time to store is "2012-02-05 8:15 AM"
So in your index, store "timestamp=1328447700" and "time=815"

Now you want to query the index for all events between 2012-02-01 and 2012-02-10 that occurred from 8:00 am to 9:00 am. You do that by querying the index for
"timestamp>=1328072400 and timestamp<=1328936399 and time>=800 and time<=900"

The exact syntax for doing this depends on how you are connecting to Neo4j (REST or embedded) and which programming language you are using. But the idea is the same in any case.

Comment: Can you please explain why mixing epoch date and `ISO8601` time is a good idea? If I were to implement it I'd go with either `20131124` and `1130` OR `1385251200` and `41400` (seconds since midnight: `(11*60+30)*60`), this way you can either concatenate the parts and parse a `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format OR do `Calendar.setTimeInMillis` with the two values added together when it needs to display.

Comment: @Phil there seems to have been some progress on this, regarding GraphAware's TimeTree. Is this still the optimal way to search for times within a certain range in neo4j? This answer seems to be very, very inefficient, because I'll have to convert every value to a timestamp, and then compare that value with every other node in the graph if additional month/year complexity isn't added.

Comment: can this be demonstrated through a simple cypher query?

Answer (score 9):

There's a convenient org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneTimeline which does this (using an integrated lucene index in neo4j).

Answer (score 5):

This is an extension to Josh Adell's answer. For readability, I suggest having two `date` and `time` integer fields like

```
date:19970716 (YYYYMMDD)
time:203045000 (HHmmssuuu): last three digits for microseconds.
```

The `int` datatype can store upto `2147483647`. If you are feeling adventurous, the `long` datatype can store upto `9223372036854775807`.
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html

---

Inspired from [ISO 8601 timestamps](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) like `1997-07-16T19:20:30.45Z`.

**Disclaimer**: I have only minimal experience with Neo4J.

Comment: That's millisecond not micro.

Answer (score 1):

```
with Spring data neo4j

     public List<Email> getAllEmailData(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
            List<Email> list = new ArrayList<Email>();
            if (startDate == null || endDate == null) {
                return null;
            }               
             long  first = ConversionsUtils.convertDateToLong(startDate);
             long  second = ConversionsUtils.convertDateToLong(endDate);         

            try {
                list = emailRepository.searchAllData(first, second);
               // System.out.println("List size " +list.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return list;
        }


         @Query(
                "START  email=node:__types__(className='com.backend.core.neo.entities.Email') "            
                + "WHERE  email.searchDate > {0} and email.searchDate < {1}"
                + "RETURN email")
        List<Email> searchAllData(long startDate, long endDate);

email entity

@NodeEntity
public class Email implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String CC = "CC";
    public static final String TO = "TO";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @GraphProperty
    private Long senderId;

    @GraphProperty
    private String subject;    

    @Indexed 
   // @GraphProperty(propertyType = java.util.Date.class)
    private String dateSent;

    @Indexed    
    private long searchDate;

    @GraphProperty
    private String emailTxt;
    @GraphProperty
    private String emailHtml;
    @GraphProperty
    private String emailId;
    //mail to
    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(elementClass = User.class, type = TO, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<User> intoUsers;
    //mail shared
    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(elementClass = User.class, type = CC, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<User> sharedUsers;
```