# Understanding Options for Building TimeTree in Neo4

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

Is it possible to construct something like GraphAware's [TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree) using Neo4j's [CLI](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell.html), GraphAware's [importer](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-importer), Michael Hunger's [batch import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import), or with py2neo?

It would be optimal to be able to do this using Neo4j's CLI (in terms of set up). I want to be able to search for a certain kind of node in a range without converting all the date values to timestamps, as encouraged by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147388/2423246). My data is currently in [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

I'm not against building a TimeTree from scratch, like what Michael Hunger did [in this post](http://jexp.github.io/blog/html/timetree.html). However, I suspect that this is a common issue and would prefer not to rediscover the wheel on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the GraphAware TimeTree, you are not limited to the rest api. Since version 2.2 you have automatic event attachment configurable in the neo4j.properties file

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree/blob/master/README.md#automatic-event-attachment

While this does not remove you the fact that you will need to convert your event times in milliseconds, there are a number of points that will ease your life :

- no need to care about building missing parts of the tree
- if an event is removed and the time node was attached to only one event, this time node will be automatically removed
- this is well tested and in production on high-demand neo4j instances
- supported by neo4j experts

It is worth to give it a try